# What is the correct way to check if a cell in a database is null

Tags: c#, sql-server, if-statement, null

I have an employee attendance project. this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_attendanceSheet] 
(
    [Id]           INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [memberCode]   NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [name]         NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [date]         NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [clockin]      NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [clockout]     NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [delay]        NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [HouresWorked] NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    [desc]         NVARCHAR (150) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I want to manage for the employees whenever they enter their code in the textbox the program record their enter or leave time.

For some reason, I have to check if some cells are null.

```
private void textBoxX1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    sqlcon.Close();
    sqlcon.Open();

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string t = lbl_Time.Text;
        string d = lbl_Date.Text;

        string selectQueryName = "SELECT name FROM tbl_attendanceMembers where memberCode=" + "'" + textBoxX1.Text + "'";
        var sqlcmdName = new SqlCommand(selectQueryName, sqlcon);
        var resultName = sqlcmdName.ExecuteScalar();

        string selectQueryId = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_attendanceSheet";
        var sqlcmdId = new SqlCommand(selectQueryId, sqlcon);
        var resultId = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

        (1)if (resultId != null)
        {
            string selectQueryCockin = "SELECT Clockin FROM tbl_attendanceSheet where id=" + "resultId";
            var sqlcmdCockin = new SqlCommand(selectQueryCockin, sqlcon);
            var resultCockin = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

           (2)if (resultCockin != null)
            {
                (3)if (resultName != null)
                {

                    this.lbl_mmbrname.Text = resultName.ToString();
                    this.lbl_timestored.Text = t;
                    textBoxX1.Clear();                       
                }    
            }
        }
        else //if result id == null
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmdClockin = new SqlCommand("InputClockIn", sqlcon);
            sqlcmdClockin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputDate", d);
            sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputTime", t);
            sqlcmdClockin.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_attendanceMembers", sqlcon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        sqlcon.Close();

    }
}
```

Whenever the equality signs in those points are **"=="**, it **jumps** **to** the **else** part.

However, whenever the equality signs in those points are **"!="**, it **goes through** all of the **ifs**. this phenomenon is regardless of nullity of the relative cells in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

I have checked program via breakpoints several times...

I have checked different situations which relative cells are null and are not null. I don't know what is wrong.

By the first `sqlcon.close();` is because if I don't write it it will say connection is not closed which doesn't make sense to me because I have written a `sqlcon.close();` down there...

Comment: "I have checked program via break poits several times... I have checked different situations which reletive cells are null and are not null." - so what was the value of resultId when you expected it to be null?

Comment: @bhmahler so how am I able to check if a database cell is null any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbCommand_ExecuteScalar

Comment: @Rup when its null and i have written if (its null) it jumps to else part. if its not and Ihave writen if (its null) again does the same thing. the vise versa is also true when I have written if(its not null) it goes through all if statements.

Comment: @bhmahler whats the difference between result not found and null? arent them the same? by default all of the values in the data base is null or not found?

Comment: Not found means no record found matching your Where clause.  Null is when the record is found but the value you are selecting is null

Comment: @bhmahler why did you delete "execute scalar always returns something." is it wrong then?

Comment: It's not wrong exactly, but in the case of not found will throw an exception per the documentation.

Comment: @bhmahler do you think if I mention both dbnull and null in the if statement, will my problem be solved?

Comment: The solution Haldo provided should do the trick for you.  Although you may want to have a try catch in case an exception is thrown

Comment: wow @bhmahler I guess your right would you please post it as an answer with a throw exception? I guess this is the answer I was looking for...

Comment: A couple of unrelated tips. Beware the SQL injection vulnerability in your code: use SQL parameters rather than string concatenation to create queries. SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. And it's worth reading [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @Richardissimo thank you for your advice I will read the link you sent. could you help me how can I throw a null refrence try/catch? I dont know how and I didnt understand those I found on the web.

Comment: Also note that `selectQueryCockin`[sic] doesn't use the value of `resultId` it gives you a query which won't work. `ExecuteScalar` returns an object, so will need converting before you can use it. Regarding *"how can I throw a null refrence try/catch"*, I don't think you know what you're asking for. The method returns null if not found so not sure what exception bmahler was referring to. The [documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) (see "Returns"). 1 of the 3 will never return null.

Comment: Oh, and please don't store your dates and times in SQL as `nvarchar`... NVarchar uses more space,.doesn't validate and will cause you pain later when you try writing queries on that column. Use `date` and `time`. Also consider what type `HouresWorked` [sic] should be, again I suspect nvarchar is a bad choice.

Comment: thank you again. will this `selectQueryCockin[sic] doesn't use the value of resultId`  be solved if I write resultID.tostring(); ?

Comment: Yes it would, but as I said earlier, you should be using SQL parameters rather than string concatenation.

Comment: yes to avoid Sql injection I got it. really I appreciate your help and time. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a database value is null use `DBNull.Value`

```
if (resultId != DBNull.Value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for DBNull.Value and also handle any exceptions that may come up

```
private void textBoxX1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    sqlcon.Close();
    sqlcon.Open();

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        try{
            string t = lbl_Time.Text;
            string d = lbl_Date.Text;

            string selectQueryName = "SELECT name FROM tbl_attendanceMembers where memberCode=" + "'" + textBoxX1.Text + "'";
            var sqlcmdName = new SqlCommand(selectQueryName, sqlcon);
            var resultName = sqlcmdName.ExecuteScalar();
            if (resultName != DBNull.Value)
            {
                string selectQueryId = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_attendanceSheet";
                var sqlcmdId = new SqlCommand(selectQueryId, sqlcon);
                var resultId = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

                if (resultId != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    string selectQueryCockin = "SELECT Clockin FROM tbl_attendanceSheet where id=" + "resultId";
                    var sqlcmdCockin = new SqlCommand(selectQueryCockin, sqlcon);
                    var resultCockin = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (resultCockin != DBNull.Value
                    {
                        this.lbl_mmbrname.Text = resultName.ToString();
                        this.lbl_timestored.Text = t;
                        textBoxX1.Clear();  
                    }
                }
            }
            else //if result id == null
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcmdClockin = new SqlCommand("InputClockIn", sqlcon);
                sqlcmdClockin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputDate", d);
                sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputTime", t);
                sqlcmdClockin.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_attendanceMembers", sqlcon);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sqlda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Do somethging with the exception if desired
        } finally {
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```